# Problem with two ROS Versions on single system

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I had ROS indigo on my system, then I decided to add the new version (Jade) as separate package. The installation was successful and now I have to folder  /opt/ros/indigo and /opt/ros/jade. However, when I try to switch to jade by sourcing the “setup.bash” file I receive the fallowing error:

```
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'jade' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
```

Moreover it seems that Gazebo is totally is replaced by the new version. That prevents me from running the turtlebot simulation. I receive the below error by running the “roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch”

```
[turtlebot_world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_gazebo] nor is [turtlebot_gazebo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Thanks
Shervin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211243/problem-with-two-ros-versions-on-single-system/) by [shervin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22781/shervin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2015-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That happens when environment is mixed. See [a previous thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/62589/problem-with-the-terminal-ros_distro/) for possible solutions.

For Gazebo issue between Indigo and Jade, see http://answers.ros.org/question/208334/gazebo-version-collides-between-indigo-and-jade/

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shervin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22781/shervin/) on 2015-06-14**:
Thank you.